# Как заполнять progress bar через button?

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на Button, Progress Bar заполнился на 1%, и при повторном его нажатии добавлялся еще +1% и так далее.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        waveLoadingView = (WaveLoadingView) findViewById(R.id.waveLoadingView);
        waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(0);

        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(1);
```

Comment: какой коду у вас уже имеется? Что сложного в вызове метода `setProgress`?

Comment: progressBar.setProgress(1)....

Comment: @Komdosh setProgress вызывал, но при нажатии на кнопку прогресс стоит в указанном setProgress-ом месте. Надо чтобы прогресс добавлялся при повторном нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Так вы наверное не увеличиваете счётчик

Comment: @Komdosh я только начинающий, подскажите пожалуйста как увеличивать счётчик?

Comment: так вы код покажите

Comment: @Komdosh добавил код

Comment: не, так не пойдёт, вам сначала нужно основы программирования разобрать.

Comment: Попробуйте так: `waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(waveLoadingView.getProgressValue() + 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью поддерживаю @Komdosh про изучение основ.
В качестве примера для старта с текущим кодом:
Счетчик не увеличивается, потому что ему задается постоянное значение

```
waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(1);
```

Для увеличения прогресса нужно получать текущее значение и добавлять нужное значение (скажем +1)

```
waveLoadingView.setProgressValue(waveLoadingView.getProgressValue() + 1);
```

Comment: "добавлять нужный инкремент" -> "добавлять нужное значение". Если это не англицизм, а название оператора, то инкремент означает увеличение на 1. Пояснение: "The increment operator increases, and the decrement operator decreases, the value of its operand by 1.". Источник: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators